# How do I pass ownership of pixel data to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, c, opencv, memory-management

I am creating a cv::Mat passing with pixel data that I have allocated externally.

```
cv::Mat myMatrix(vImageResult.height,
                 vImageResult.width,
                 CV_8UC1,
                 vImageResult.data);
```

I would like the cv::Mat to take ownership of the bytes (i.e. create a refCount and free the bytes when it reaches zero) .  However the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) says

> Matrix constructors that take data and step parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. **The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.**

- If I free the underlying `vImageResult.data` immediately, the I will get a bad access crash somewhere down the line.
- If I don't free the underlying `vImageResult.data` then the data will leek.

Is there a way to pass ownership?

Comment: What's wrong with just doing `myMatrix=vImageResult`?

Comment: @AldurDisciple vImageResult might not be a cv::Mat. This should be what is meant by "allocated externally" and is what I assumed when writing my answer.

Comment: I dont think you can do this, because Mat does not know how you allocated the memory(malloc, new, etc), and hence, does not know how to free it.

Comment: IIRC - the solution was to create the cv::Mat, grab the underlying bytes and pass them to the external program to manipulate.  That way cv::Mat keeps ownership since it created them in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

cv::Mat does not know how you allocated the memory(malloc, new, etc), and hence, does not know how to free it.

If you are allocating the data yourself, you could always call `cv::Mat::create(...)` to allocate the memory you need, and then pass the pointer `myMatrix.data` to whatever function you are using to load the data.

If you're referring to pre-allocated memory provided to you through a video capture stream or external library, you're out of luck.

Andreas' solution will work, but can be slow if used frequently.

A compromise may be to wrap `cv::Mat` in your own type:

```
struct MyMat
{
    cv::Mat mat;
    MyMat(int width, int height, int format, char *data)
        : mat(height, width, format, data){}
    ~MyMat() { delete [] mat.data; }
};
```

Note: it was intentional not to try and subclass cv::Mat. It does not have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 5):

An option is to copy the data to a new matrix using `Mat::clone()`, which performs a deep copy of the data. The new matrix will then have ownership of the cloned data.

For example:

```
// create temporary matrix that holds the external/old data
cv::Mat tmp(vImageResult.height,
            vImageResult.width,
            CV_8UC1,
            vImageResult.data); 
cv::Mat myMatrix = tmp.clone(); // myMatrix now has ownership of a clone of the data.
```

Comment: and original data can be free'd immediately after the copy. That's what I suggest too, although it's strictly speaking not an answer to the question :D

Comment: Right (to both points). As far as I can see in the docs, there is no way of passing ownership, so this option would be closest to what the OP wants.

Comment: @anderas you must be right in assuming `vImageResult` is not a `cv::Mat`, but then maybe you should add a few details on how to use `clone()` to pass ownership.