# Opencv Mat memory management

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Memory management is essential for an image class. In opencv, the image class is `cv::Mat`, which has a delicate memory management scheme. Suppose I already have my own image class `SelfImage`:

```
class SelfImage
{
  public:
    int width_;
    int height_;
    unsigned char *pPixel_;    
};
```

At the beginning, I will put all the image pixel contents to this class:

```
SelfImage myImage;
myImage.width_ = 300;
myImage.height_ = 200;
myImage.pPixel_ = new [300*200];
for(int i=0; i<300*200; i++)
      myImage.pPixel_[i] = i%200;
```

Then my question is how I can transform this class to `cv::Mat` in a very efficient way, one solution I have is:

```
  cv::Mat mat;
    mat.create( myImage.height_, myImage.width_, CV_8UC1);
    mat.data = myImage.pPixel_;
```

I do not know whether this is a good solution. If `cv::Mat::create` function will also allocate memory,then the above codes have the danger of memory leak. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
  I have to make it clear that it would be nice if I can use `cv::Mat::create` method but share the memory with `SelfImage` class.The reason is that a function is defined to perfom the image class transform job `void TransImageType(const SelfImage &geo_img, cv::Mat &mat)`;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cv::Mat` [has a constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) where you can specify user data:

```
Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

The documentation says the following about the `data` argument:

> Pointer to the user data. Matrix constructors that take data and step
>   parameters do not allocate matrix data. Instead, they just initialize
>   the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that
>   no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can be used to
>   process external data using OpenCV functions. The external data is not
>   automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

Comment: I have to make it clear that it would be nice if I can use `cv::Mat::create` method but share the memory with `SelfImage` class.

Comment: I don't think that's possible... See [that related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511747/how-do-i-pass-ownership-of-pixel-data-to-cvmat). Why exactly can't you use that constructor?

Comment: Thanks, and the reason is that a function is defined to perfom the image class transform job  void TransImageType(const SelfImage &geo_img, cv::Mat &mat);

Comment: In that case why don't you do `mat = cv::Mat(geo_img.height_, geo_img.width_, CV_8U, geo_img.pPixel_);` in the body of your function?

Comment: Thanks, and I did not realize that I can call cv::Mat in this way. I am not familiar with cv::Mat, and when I see codes like mat = cv::Mat(geo_img.height_, geo_img.width_, CV_8U, geo_img.pPixel_);I thought it would involve deep copying.

Comment: No, when you do that, only the `cv::Mat` header is copied (rows, cols, type, etc), the underlying pixel data is the same.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you want to copy the data.

From your suggestion, it seems you want to share the data. In that case, this is the best solution:

```
cv::Mat mat(myImage.height_, myImage.width_, CV_8U, myImage.pPixel_);
```

The `mat` will not release the memory when it is deallocated, you will have to do it.

If you want to copy data, create a normal `cv::Mat` and do `std::copy` later (or `memcpy` as @KeillRandor suggested).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but here I cannot directly use cv::Mat mat(myImage.height_, myImage.width_, CV_8U, myImage.pPixel_).

Answer (score 1):

`Mat::create()` allocates data (`total()*elemSize()` bytes) and initializes the internal reference counter of the allocated data to 1, (except when the `Mat` already existed and had the same size/type specified in the `create()` method).

And yes, your code **produces a memory leak** since the data allocated by `Mat::create()` is lost when you move the `Mat::data` pointer.

The proper way to do it should be (in my opinion) by using `memcpy` from `myImage.pPixel_` to `mat.data` (after calling `create()`). This may seem inefficient, but the good side is that the `Mat` destructor will handle the data deallocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
Mat mat = Mat(myImage.height_, myImage.width_, CV_8UC1, myImage.pPixel_);
```

In this way, no data is copied. And, of course, as the price, you should take care of releasing the memory.

From its [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat):

> [...] Instead, they just initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that no data is copied. This operation is very efficient and can be used to process external data using OpenCV functions. The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it.

Comment: I have to make it clear that it would be nice if I can use `cv::Mat::create` method but share the memory with `SelfImage` class.